# When I run a process in a detached screen section it becomes very slow

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I am not so into Linux and I have the following situation related a strange behavior of the `screen` command.

The situation is the following one: one a Raspberry Pi I have installed Raspbian - when I connect to the Raspberry using SSH and do the following operations:

1. I create a new screen session to run a program to keep it running when I off  from ssh. The program is CPU miner, a program used to mine BitCoin\LiteCoin and it use a GridSeed that is an USB ASIC hardware that do the work (but I think that this is not so important)
2. I type 'Ctrl AD' to exit the screen session so I log off from SSH.

The problem is that when I detached the screen session the performance decreases dramatically - it does exactly a sixth of the work that it do when the session is not detached.

So I have no idea about this behavior and I can think only two thing:

1. When a session is detached the priority of its process is decreased
2. Maybe the Raspberry hardware is not powerful enough and it can't appropriately handle the process in a detached screen session.

What is the problem? what am I missing? what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: This is the first report I read about such processing power decrease. Please give us more information about it: 1-open, in another SSH session, the utility "top" and tell us if the priority and niceness levels get changed and the amount of CPU consumed by the process; 2-prepend the execution of your miner with the "time" once outside screen and another inside it, letting it run for the same amount of time the two times and please show us the answer; 3-try to decrease the niceness level of your miner, prepend it with the "nice -n -20 <command>" (must be root). And lets see if I can help.

Comment: Did you try this? I would be interested in the results. Just tried it with `find` within `screen` and neither screen nor find change priority, niceness when detaching the screen. CPU-load of the process is also not changing...